# Improper parsing of String to DateTime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas having two fields:

```
UsageStartDate        UsageEndDate

5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM  5/1/2020 11:59:59 PM
```

I am trying to convert them to 24-hour format.

I am using the following:

```
df['UsageStartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UsageStartDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
df['UsageEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UsageEndDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

The `UsageEndDate` field gives proper output: `2020-05-01 23:59:59`

However, the `UsageStartDate` gives: `2020-05-01`

I also tried to parse the date during reading of the csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/sample.csv', parse_dates=['UsageStartDate', 'UsageEndDate'])
```

It returned the same result as above.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will display fields without trailing zeros, as an aesthetic choice. Your actual Timestamp value is correct:

```
df['UsageStartDate'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

0   2020-05-01 00:00:01
Name: UsageStartDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you want the full value as a string, you can get it with the Timestamp string formatter, [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
df['UsageStartDate'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

0    05/01/2020 12:00:00 AM
Name: UsageStartDate, dtype: object # <- Note that this is now object type
```